# Add checker board texture to a plane

Tags: texturing

I am working with blender and I am trying to add a checker board texture to a plane that is on the back ground. this is how I was able to get it:

[image]

I am not able to make it into a solid texture, that doesnt look like this but an actual checker board.

this is my workstation in blender:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your file or just a copy of the object with the checker texture, you could upload to [pateall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) and paste the link here. It looks like you are mixing two checkers together, maybe with an odd vector input, the key data is hidden inside the collapsed part that says Checker Texture.

Comment: Looks to me like you have it set as the world background. It'll likely work better (with more control) if you create a mesh plane in the background set the checkers as a texture there.